# Android Voice Activity Detection (VAD) Using Opus Codec

Tags: android, voice-recognition, codec, opus

It's my understanding that Android supports the Audio Codec Opus since 5.0. (https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) This codec should store VAD data, which can be parsed.

Has anyone managed to achieve this in Android, and are any examples available online? I'm specifically looking for the recording/saving of Audio, and then parsing of the VAD data from within these files.

Comment: There are many implementations for opus codec for Android like https://github.com/actorapp/droidkit-opus You need to be a bit more specific and provide the code

Comment: I'm specifically referring to the support included in Android 5.0+, and not community based solutions. But I'm unable to find out how to use it, and MediaRecorder class does not seem to provide any support.

Comment: There is no way analyze it, you can just play or record it. You have to use community-based solutions.